# Read RGGB / non-demosaiced / Bayer pixels in Swift

Tags: swift, image, core-graphics, core-image, raw

I would like to:

1. read a RAW image in Swift,
2. access the image's Bayer matrix as a MTLTexture,
3. modify the Bayer matrix,
4. demosaic the modified image.

However, I cannot manage to read a RAW image without demosaicing it. E.g., when I load the image using a CIFilter, I can only access the demosaiced image, *not* the Bayer matrix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the end, I couldn't manage to do this in [Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage). I tried [LibRaw](https://www.libraw.org) but it doesn't preserve full image quality. I ended up using [Adobe DNG SDK](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/digital-negative.html), which supports DNG files only but maintains full image quality. You can find my solution [here](https://github.com/martin-marek/hdr-plus-swift/blob/main/burstphoto/dng_utils.swift).